# best way to establish a relationship between 3 models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have these 3 models: and here is what i need:

Basically I have `records`, and a `user` must hold a specific `role` assigned to him to be able to make changes to that `record`. each different `record` can have multiple `roles` and each `role` can belong to many different versions of a `record`. now that im having a version control, each single role can belong to many different versions of a record( different versions of the one record can be associated through the common secondary_id attribute for records).

What is the best way to establish this relationship between the three models?

thanks

Comment: So, if I get you, a user has one or more roles.  A record has one or more roles.  If a user has a record, AND the user and the record share at least one role, the user can manage the record?

Why would a user have a record and not have a role for it?  Or, is there really no need for a relationship between user and record?

Comment: as it stand there is no direct relationship with users and records, but i want to implement the authorisation logic with cancan where i want to have somthing like: ``can :manage, Record do |record|
        user.records_for_edit.include?(record)
     end`` is there another way i can do this without a direct relationship between users and records

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change your `User` model:

```
class User
  has_many :roles
  has_many :records

  def has_access_to?(obj)
    roles.exists?(:id => obj.role_ids)
  end    
end
```

Controller code:

```
class RecordsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_user  # checks if the user is logged in
  before_filter :load_record, :except => [:index]
  before_filter :require_permission, :except => [:new, :create, :index]

private

  def require_permission
    return true if current_user.has_access_to?(@record)
    render :text => "You don't have permission to complete this action.",
           :status => '401 Unauthorized'
    return false
  end

  def load_record
    case(action.to_sym)
    when :new, :create
      @record = current_user.records.build(params[:record])
    when :edit, :update, :show, :destroy
      @record = current_user.records.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i think you misunderstood my question. i really appreciate the effort you put in to the answer.  i made changes to the question.

Comment: The `has_access_to?` method should address your requirement ( i.e. it will check to see if any of the roles assigned to the user are in the roles required by the user). If you are looking for the presence of a specific role, you can extend the method. If your requirements are different than this, your question doesn't convey that. May be you can add some pseudo code to show what you need.

Comment: I used it like so in the cancan ability model: ``can :manage, Records do |records|
        user.has_access_to?(record)
     end`` and it gives me this error: ``undefined method `role_ids' for [:edit, nil]:Array`` but what i meant is how do i establish the relationships with the three models? whats the rails way to do it? do i use a has_many through or habtm etc?

Comment: I made more changes to the question to explain it better, sorry about the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Use cancan, http://github.com/ryanb/cancan. It'll give you exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i think you misunderstood the question, i made the changes to make it clearer. sorry about that.